# iterate array to create hibernate criteria statement

Tags: java, hibernate

let say my array has 3 integer object value= 3,4,5
i would need to create hibernate criteria that look like below

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.eq(
        "stepId", new Integer(3))), Restrictions.and(Restrictions
        .not(Restrictions.eq("stepId", new Integer(4))), Restrictions
        .not(Restrictions.eq("stepId", new Integer(5))))));
```

the above criteria is created manually, i wonder can automate this through iteration

```
for(Iterator iterator = integerArray.iterator; iterator.hasNext()){
    // create the criteria above
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Disjunction](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0350__Hibernate/RestrictionsDisjunction.htm) in your loop:

```
Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
for(Iterator iterator = integerArray.iterator; iterator.hasNext()){
    disjunction.add(yourRestriction); //add your restirction here
}
criteria.add(disjunction );
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [in](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#in%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[]%29) restriction while takes `Array` argument.

```
  Integer[] integerArray = ...
  criteria.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.not(
        Restrictions.in("stepId", integerArray)
  );
```